# Google Analytics API (GA4) v1alpha:runReport

Tags: google-analytics-api

POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/**v1alpha:runReport**

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/TopLevel/runReport

Something changed with the new Google Analytics API for GA4?
That’s an error.
The requested URL `/v1alpha:runReport` was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The v1 alpha version of the Data API has been deprecated and turned off. Please use the [Data API v1 beta](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/) instead.